# How to find accounts that do not have a specific Account Contact Relationship role?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

we would like to create a report that tells us which Accounts do not have a contact with a specific role.  We are using lightning and the Account Contact Relationships junction object.  We have created a report type for Accounts with or without Contact Relationships.

What we would like to see on the report is any account that does not have at least one contact that has the role of say "Influencer".  If the account has one or more contacts in the role "influencer" it should be excluded from the report.

We tried using a cross filter on Accounts with Contact Relationships and Roles excluding "Influencer" but it wasn't returning the correct results.

Can this be type of report be created with salesforce reports?